# Subclassing UINavigationController for custom navigation between Views

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am making a small app with the following view hierarchy with UINavigationController:

> Login -> Options -> three different views

The problem is that I would like to navigate between the last 3 views in the following manner:

```
1<->2
1<->3
2<->3
```

i.e. to be able to switch to any view from any other view, which reminds UITabViewController functionality. So, it is not hierarchical, it is any-to-any graph. To switch between views I will use buttons in the navigation bar.

The easiest way for me is to subclass UINavigationController, add properties that correspond to my views and implement methods for switching between these views (using pushViewController and popToRootViewController). These methods will be called from the views for switching (navigating).

However the reference says that UINavigationController is not intended for subclassing. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: I don't think that subclass UINavigationController is a good idea. Besides, I think it's not under NDA.
Do you have an idea of what kind of transition you want between the views ?

Comment: The transition I need is just a simple built-in animated transition. The idea is to have these all VC in a stack and then show a VC depending on the button pressed in a current VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll keep the `UINavigationController` but instead of using the usual `pushViewController:`, switch views like this:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    // from here you can modify the order of controllers as much as you want
[viewControllers addObject:nextViewController];
[viewControllers removeObject:self];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

If you don't want how the animation turns out, you can set `animated:NO` and either enclose `setViewControllers:` in an `[UIView animate...]` block, or add your own custom `CAAnimation` to the navigation controller's layer.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of using setViewControllers as a workaround. However the following is not clear to me: I need to have my personal stack of these 3 ViewControllers and put them in a right order into UINavigationController stack for navigating. Where should I store so that each of these VC will have access to the stack?

Comment: You can reorder the `navigationController.viewControllers` however much you want. You don't need to store anything because you are just using the default navigation controller stack; you are just providing custom ordering instead of the common push-pop one. You don't even need to keep an instance of all the viewControllers; just recreate each one as the user goes along. This way you can create the illusion of an infinite navigation stack.

Comment: I plan to create a method like "performSwitchToViewControllerByTitle:(String)vcTitle" in each of the views. Inside the method I will get a NSArray of VCs from UINavigatorController, put VC with title==vcTitle in the end of the array and then put the array back. The only thing that I don't like is that I need to create instances of my VCs during first transitions (when needed), so each VC will have to include header files of other VCs.

Comment: You can avoid the dependencies between the view controllers by appointing an object to keep those references. You can either create a singleton, or make a UINavigationController subclass. Personally, I'll go with the latter.

Comment: Done! I've put a dictionary of my cyclic views to the subclassed UINavigation controller. I also put there a function that switches to a given view by its title (using view reordering). So, each other ViewController can call this function. The only thing that worries me is that I do "unobvious" lazy instantiation of my cyclic views when I have a call of my switchViewByTitle function. I do their instantiation by their storyboard id. So the name must be equals to storyboard id.

Comment: Your design seems sound. Lazy initialization is not as bad as you think. You're actually better prepared if you decide to implement state-restoration in the future.

Comment: I've found a drawback in that design. I cannot do proper data transmission between my views. It is usually done in prepareForSegue. So, I'm thinking of using Segues. I suppose that Segues will call [NavigationControlloer pushViewController]. If it is correct, then I have to override pushViewController with objective-C category. What do you think about this?

Comment: I've just realized that overriding methods with categories was a bad idea.

Comment: If you really wanted to use segues, it'll be more elegant to just subclass `UIStoryboardSegue` and do the above code inside the `perform` method. That way you can also use it in your storyboard.

Comment: I figured out that UIStoryboardSegue is created by storyboard. It automatically creates the ViewController to which I want to segue. I can later specify it by myself in perform method. However the automatically created VC stays in memory. So, I returned to my previous solution with custom Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to add a view controller to a navigation controller,

Navigating From first -> second

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSMutableArray *navigationarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [navigationarray removeAllObjects];
    [navigationarray addObject:secondView];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationarray;
```

Navigating From first -> third

```
ThirdViewController *thirdView = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSMutableArray *navigationarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [navigationarray removeAllObjects];
    [navigationarray addObject:thirdView];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationarray;
```

The above code will removes all the viewControllers from the Navigation Array and places a fresh View Controller

If u want to go to a particular view controller, then use the below code...

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES]

Change the index to ur view controller in the stack.

Comment: Thank you. However I do not want to instantiate a new VC every time when I need to switch to it. I need to push it from my stack of VCs. Also, I will need to return to the RootViewController at some point in time, which I also need to preserve somewhere.

Comment: I've already implemented according to the other suggestion which is more suitable with regard to VC instance management.